# Why is there circular dependency problem in this scenario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

The code here is just a simpler version of code that I am working on. I've similar case situation in my project. All I want to know is why is it happening circular error for this case and how to resolve it! Thanks in advance.

First I want to show you the working condition (i.e. no circular dependency).

Note: `ball.py` will contain a decorator and `main.py` will be entrance to our project

**Working Project Structure:**

```
> Project
  |-> apple.py
  |-> ball.py
  |-> main.py
```

**apple.py**

```
def apple_beautifier():
    print("Decorator from apple!")

from ball import decorator

@decorator
def apple_printer():
    print("Apple!!")
```

**ball.py**

```
from apple import apple_beautifier
# from cat import cat_beautifier

def decorator(func):
    def inner():
        apple_beautifier()
        # cat_beautifier()
        func()
    return inner
```

*<sup># The commented part will be added for **Not working case**</sup>*

**main.py**

```
from apple import apple_printer

if __name__=="__main__":
    apple_printer()
```

The program runs fine and you get output:

```
Decorator from apple!
Apple!!
```

Now, add a third file, `cat.py`. So project structure is now:

**Fail Project Structure:**

```
> Project
  |-> apple.py
  |-> ball.py
  |-> cat.py
  |-> main.py
```

**cat.py**

```
def cat_beautifier():
    print("Decorator from cat!")

from ball import decorator

@decorator
def cat_printer():
    print("Cat!!")
```

If you re-run the program now. You will get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'decorator' from partially initialized module 'ball' 
(most likely due to a circular import) (ball.py)
```

#### Python version: 3.8.5

Comment: The circular imports occur because you have arranged your code like that. The resolution to the above code is to move `apple_beautifier` into, say, `beautifier.py`. Also, in the future, arrange your modules so that all the imports are at the top. This will inform you of circular imports sooner.

Comment: umm. But It works when there is only one import (the first case). But when I added second file with same structure. The import cycle breaks. any specific reason?

Comment: "apple.py" — I see what you did there…

Comment: @deceze Isnt this a way how we are supposed to resolve circular dependency by defining import at bottom?

Comment: Well, in my book we resolve circular dependencies by using a hierarchical structure where elements at a particular level can refer to other elements in the same module, or in modules below its current level and never modules above.

Comment: Hehe. @quamrana thank you for reading me your book. I'll address that solution. But when things breaks, it always makes me curious. Now I want to know what break the second case. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I say *my book*, but of course I’m really referring to Uncle Bob.

Comment: No. you were right in the design concept. But I'll try debugging it once :)